# Is a 'for loop' a function?

Tags: python, c, syntax

Is a 'for loop' a function? If not, what is it? How it works?

Example in C:

```
for(int i=0; i<32; i++)
{
    ...
}
```

Example in Python:

```
for i in range(0, 32):
    print "..."
```

Comment: No, it is a *keyword*: a function is an object that transforms input in output. A for does not do that.

Comment: It is a keyword which notates control flow.

Comment: Hum... Make sense... Thanks! Should i delete the post?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem nopes, _for loop_ is not a keyword, it's a statement which contains the `for` keyword.

Comment: It's also not a function in python either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the whole *thing* is called "iteration statement". The one which includes the `for` keyword is called `for` statement.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 6.8,

> A *statement* specifies an action to be performed. [...]

and from §6.8.5

> iteration-statement:
>
> ```
> while ( expression ) statement
>
> do statement while ( expression ) ;
>
> for ( expressionopt ; expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
>
> for ( declaration expressionopt ; expressionopt ) statement
> ```

Comment: Could you give us the reference?

Comment: Could you provide the link?

Comment: The actual spec costs money, however some draft version you can get online.

Comment: Ok! I will search it! Thanks! ;)

Comment: @BrennoLeal [here's one, if you want](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html). :)

Comment: How about if statement?

Comment: But conceptually IT IS a function inside another function. So it IS a function! Just with different syntax.

Answer (score 2):

If you go down to assembler level and basic CPU instructions, what is a function? A function is just some block of code that is surrounded by JMP (jump) instructions. So, instruction pointer (instruction that is currently executed) jumps from some other place in program to the start of a function, executes it's code, and then jumps somewhere else.

In this sense, a loop is definitely a function. Only slight difference is that it usually jumps to it's own beginning to check some condition and execute itself again, instead of jumping to some other place (usually place of its call).

Yes, on higher abstraction levels it differs from functions greatly, but on basic level it is function. You can think of it as function inside another function. So you should always treat your loops as "autonomous islands" in your functions.

Answer (score 1):

No, `for` loop is a **iterative conditional statement** in c and c++.

C book **n1256** paragraph **6.8.5.3** The for statement

> The statement
>
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 )
>
> statement
> behaves as follows: The expression expression-2 is the controlling
> expression that is evaluated before each execution of the loop body.
> The expression expression-3 is evaluated as a void expression after
> each execution of the loop body. If clause-1 is a declaration, the
> scope of any identifiers it declares is the remainder of the
> declaration and the entire loop, including the other two expressions;
> it is reached in the order of execution before the first evaluation of
> the controlling expression. If clause-1 is an expression, it is
> evaluated as a void expression before the first evaluation of the
> controlling expression.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, any object with an **iterable method** can
>   be used in a **for loop** in Python. Even **strings**, despite not having an
>   iterable method - but we'll not get on to that here. Having an
>   iterable method basically means that the data can be presented in list
>   form, where there's multiple values in an orderly fashion. You can
>   define your own iterables by creating an object with next() and iter()
>   methods.

You can see more details from [For loop Python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Answer (score 1):

A for-loop is not a function; rather, it is an iterative statement that had a condition header (for example: *the counter "i" should not be greater than or less than **any** number n, while i is incremented by a certain number for every loop iteration*). The condition header should not be seen as the parameters of the for-loop. The for-loop also has a body of code enclosed in curly braces (only referring to C-language here).

The difference between a function and the for-loop should be obvious in the C-language:

- A function is only called in another function; it cannot be defined inside another function. Hence, the for-loop cannot be a function as it has code defined the curly braces found ***inside the function it is being implemented in***.

So we cannot have something like:

```
 int main()
 {
    void AnyFunction() // cannot define a function inside another function. It can only be called
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

But we *can* have something like:

```
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // If this is a function, how can we define it inside another function?
    {
        printf("Hello");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But conceptually IT IS a function inside another function. So it IS a function! Just with different syntax.

Answer (score 0):

for is a keyword and range is a function which takes range of values as a parameter to manipulate the body of loop.